# Sort EKReminder based on due date

Tags: ios, nssortdescriptor, nsdatecomponents, eventkit, ekeventkit

I have an array of `EKReminder` objects and I would like to sort them by due date.

This seems easy at first, doing something like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dueDate" ascending:YES];

[remindersArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[dateDescriptor]];
```

However the due date of an `EKReminder` is an `NSDateComponents` object not an `NSDate`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `dateFromComponents:` to get a date and sort on the date?

Comment: Thanks, but how do I sort on that date?

Comment: A date is just a number of seconds, so it is naturally sortable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after some research I managed to solve it relatively easy:

```
[allReminders sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1,id obj2){
        EKReminder *reminder1 = obj1;
        EKReminder *reminder2 = obj2;

        NSDate *date1 = [reminder1.dueDateComponents date];
        NSDate *date2 = [reminder2.dueDateComponents date];
        return [date1 compare:date2];
     }];
```

Hope this helps someone!